# Common ConfigurationSection for multiple Websites

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I have a config section that is the same throughout several web applications and services and I would like to use one single file for that. I know that you can use `<MyCustomSection configSource="externalfile.config" />` but this only works for files inside the application folder structure. I'm looking to put this file in the parent folder, where all the apps are. Any solution?

I'm using `ConfigurationSection` class and web.config and app.config xml files.
I'm interested how to structure the .config files as well as what code to use for this.

Comment: Perhaps this will help (https://dailydotnettips.com/sharing-single-configuration-in-multiple-projects/)

Comment: while this is quite a good approach by linking, I would like to have the web.config file with all it's setting for the current app inside the current app and only a part of the config that is common in all of them to be externalised. Basically to have 2 areas of configuration. First, in the web.config, the usual way, and a section that is read from the different file, located somewhere outside the app folder.

Answer (score -1):

This is what the machine.config could be used for. Used to share values between multiple applications on the same server.

Comment: I only want to use this between several apps and that's it. I don't want all the apps on the server access it.